# android - suspend threads running while other activity is in screen

Tags: android, multithreading

I have 2 Activty: A and B.
The first (A) create and start 3 threads.

When the user insert to the second activity(B) , I need all the threads to be suspend until the user return to A activity.

I try to do it with onPause() and onResume(), but It seems not good and also not work: (On activity a)

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    Const.isWainting = true;
    super.onPause();
    try {
        synchronized(Const.shop){
        Const.shop.wait();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if(Const.isWainting == true){
        synchronized(Const.shop){
        Const.shop.notifyAll();
        Const.isWainting = false;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: One of the run method after the suggested solution below:

```
@Override
public void run()
{

    while (true)
    {

        if (this.isInterrupted() && Const.isWainting){
            synchronized (Const.shop) {
                try {
                    Const.shop.wait();
                    Const.isWainting = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


        for(int i=0; i<Const.MAX_FOOD ; i++){

            if(foodArr[i].getStatus() != Const.NOT_ACTIVE){

                //move the food one step            
                foodArr[i].move();


                if(foodArr[i].getY() > Const.screenHeight){ 
                    foodArr[i].setStatus(Const.NOT_ACTIVE);
                }
                gameView.postInvalidate();
            }

        }

        if (isInterrupted() && Const.isWainting){
            synchronized (Const.shop) {
                try {
                    Const.shop.wait();
                    Const.isWainting = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        try
        {
            FoodThread.sleep(5);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the thread doesnt stop becuase the food continue go down , even the "move" in one loop  is only one pixel -> all the food disapper from the screen or move to much down...

Please help, Thanks a lot!

**EDIT 2:**
*A activity:*

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    Const.isWainting = true;
    this.threadAnimal.interrupt();
    this.threadFood.interrupt();
    this.threadMoney.interrupt();

}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    Const.isWainting = false;
    if(Const.isWainting == true){
        synchronized(Const.shop){

            Const.shop.notifyAll();

        }
    }

}
```

*One of the thread:*

```
@Override
    public void run()
    {

        while (true)
        {

            if (this.isInterrupted() && Const.isWainting){
                synchronized (Const.shop) {
                    try {
                        Const.shop.wait();

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }




            for(int i=0; i<Const.MAX_FOOD ; i++){

                if(foodArr[i].getStatus() != Const.NOT_ACTIVE){


                    foodArr[i].move();


                    if(foodArr[i].getY() > Const.screenHeight){ 
                        foodArr[i].setStatus(Const.NOT_ACTIVE);
                    }
                    gameView.postInvalidate();
                }

            }

            if (isInterrupted() && Const.isWainting){
                synchronized (Const.shop) {
                    try {
                        Const.shop.wait();

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            try
            {
                FoodThread.sleep(5);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of object is Const.shop? What do it's wait and notifyAll methods look like?

Comment: Const.shop is from type Object. The method is Object's methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `shop.wait()` from the main thread when you call it in `onPause`. You have to call it from the threads that you want to stop. First, instead of using `Const.isWaiting` as a public variable, make it private and give it synchronized getter and setters (for example `isWaiting()` and `setWaiting(boolean waiting)`). (This step might be unnessary, though, because I think a single boolean value is already thread safe.)

Then:

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    Const.setWaiting(true);
    for (Thread t in myThreeThreads) {
        try {
           t.interrupt();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And in each of those threads, in whatever loop they are performing, they should periodically do:

```
if (isInterrupted() && Const.isWaiting()){
    synchronized (Const.shop) {
        Const.shop.wait();
    }
}
```

Or if they are doing non-loop stuff as well, do the above before each long-running action.

EDIT: I think you should also update your `onResume` to ensure that the `isWaiting` variable is unset first.

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    Const.setWaiting(false); //Now if a thread is just now getting to an interrupt check, it can just skip it and keep going.
    synchronized(Const.shop){
        Const.shop.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok i tried it. It seems great solution for me but it's didn't work - the thread contionue running..Why it can happen?

Comment: The thread will keep running until it reaches a point where it checks `isInterrupted()`. Maybe it will help if you can post the run method of one of your threads.

Comment: You're calling `Const.isWainting = false;` from within your thread, unlike my sample code above. That will prevent the other two threads from waiting. The reason for `&& Const.isWaiting()` in the if statement in my code is that it is possible that the activity resumed by the time the thread gets back to that point, so if that happens you need to avoid pausing the thread, because there won't be any unpause notifications coming after the activity resumes.

Comment: Are the three threads just doing something for a game loop? If so, wouldn't it be much easier to just put them all in the same thread and stack their run methods sequentially?

Comment: I really did a mistake by putting Const.isWainting = false; in the thread run function. But even when I remove this I get the same problem...  -> I edit again the question (and about your last comment, maybe you are right - I will think about it -thank!)

Comment: You're new `onResume` method is different than mine. It sets isWaiting to false, and then only calls `notifyAll` if isWaiting is true, so it will never happen.

Comment: I now remove the "isInterupt" in the if sentenct and it is work

Answer (score 2):

This is a real bad design. If you start a thread in an Activity and stop it onStop() then either the activity gets destroyed (and mabye so does your thread) but the worse case is: the activty cannot be destroyed in the background - boom massive memory leak - you get a new activity but the old one can be dereferenced.

Its way better to use [services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for this kind of use case

Comment: That is true...it is very convoluted. I think they would have to move this logic from onPause to the code that opens the other activity, and call notifyAll in the onDestroy method, and add a boolean representing activity life to replace while(true) in each of the threads. Then cross fingers.